# Node.js/Express Caching

Tags: caching, google-chrome, node.js, express, browser-cache

I'm pretty new to Node.js/Express, but I think I'm slowly getting the hang of it. I've added this code, which from what I can tell seems to be pretty standard:

```
app.configure('production', function() {
    var oneYear = 31557600000;
    app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public', { maxAge: oneYear }));
    app.use(express.errorHandler());
});
```

A peek into Chrome's cache reveals that, yes, everything is caching. Hurray! But when I run Chrome's audits on my site (and, I've noticed, on other Node-powered sites), Chrome says that the site isn't caching anything. What could cause this discrepancy?

Comment: Did you set your environment with 'production' before you ran it?

Comment: Yep, running with Nodejitsu which automatically uses 'production' as default. Running it locally in production mode produces the header max-age=0 on all resources. It seems maybe Chrome is caching just to be safe, as the Inspector reveals nothing in the cache.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express.createServer();
var oneYear = 31557600000;
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public', { maxAge: oneYear }));
app.use(express.errorHandler());
app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.send('hello world');
});
app.listen(3000);
```

Executing the code above, and navigating to a test.html page which lies in /public directory and has a test image gives me the following response headers and Chrome Audit is just fine on my PC (Chrome 17.0.963.83, Linux, Node 0.6.13, Express latest). You should double check if it is really in production mode.

```
Accept-Ranges:bytes
Cache-Control:public, max-age=31557600
Connection:keep-alive
Date:Fri, 23 Mar 2012 22:52:24 GMT
ETag:"120877-1278958150000"
Last-Modified:Mon, 12 Jul 2010 18:09:10 GMT
X-Powered-By:Express
```

Comment: So I'm an idiot... I was looking at the Cache-Control header of my request and not the response.

But I still have issues with the Chrome audit... when I run it locally in production mode, everything's fine: Cache-Control header's correct and Chrome audit doesn't complain.

When I deploy to Nodejitsu, however, the Cache-Control is still correct (which means it must be using production mode) but now Chrome's audits say nothing is caching.